# Grep first 50 lines of files for pattern

Tags: grep

How might one **search the first 50 lines of files in a directory for a given string**? I'm specifically looking for which database table files (from mysqldump) define a specific field, but I don't want to grep the whole files, which after 20-40 lines of CREATE TABLE continue on to hundreds of INSERT statements.

I could **write a Python script** to iterate over the first few lines of each file, but from experience Python, though powerful, is slow. I have over 200 *.sql files to go through, and I'd like to learn a solution which I could generalize in the future anyway.

Comment: Python would be done by now.

Comment: `grep` is originally made to find everything matching a given pattern. You're effectively looking for `inverse grep`. It would be a nice addition to the available toolkit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This solution works, but I feel that it is clumsy. Searching the first 50 lines for the string "foobar":

```
$ for I in *.sql ; do echo $I && head -n 50 $I | grep foobar ; done
```

Comment: Do you search in first 50 lines of each file OR first 50 pattern occurance in each file?

Comment: You could make this slightly less clumsy with `for I in *.sql ; do echo $I && grep foobar <(head -50 "$I"); done` or, to only print the file name if it matched: `for I in *.sql ; do grep foobar <(head -50 "$I") && echo "$I"; done` (but that will print the file name _after_ the matches.

Comment: @Terdon this will print the filename before the matches: `for I in *.sql; do M=$(head -50 "$I" | grep foobar) && echo "$I ==>" && echo "$M"; done`

Comment: With GNU `grep` you can use the `--label` option to add the file name. And **please quote your variables and stop using `echo` and mark the end of your options**.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas What's wrong with `echo`?

Comment: @ArturGaspar - if you hit [votes](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes) on top of the page, you'll find the answer in one of the top ten questions.

Answer (score 10):

`awk` (assuming [your implementation supports the `nextfile` statement](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=607)) can do this quite nicely:

```
awk 'FNR > 50 { nextfile }; /foobar/ { print FILENAME ": " $0 }' ./*.sql
```

The first statement skips to the next file once 50 records have been processed. The second statement prints the filename and the matching line for any line containing `foobar`.

If your `awk` doesn't have `nextfile` this variant works too, although I imagine it will be less efficient:

```
awk 'FNR <= 50 && /foobar/ { print FILENAME ": " $0 }' ./*.sql
```

Comment: Why are you doing `./*.sql` instead of just `*.sql` ?

Comment: [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%c3%a9phane-chazelas) added that, to avoid problems with filenames containing `=`. (See the [edit history for this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/197863/revisions)).

Comment: Why what difference does it make to filenames with `=` in ?

Comment: @JID, Try for instance after `touch ORS=foo.sql`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Ahh right, thanks for the example. I don't need to try it, I can see how that would be a problem. I never notice things like this because i don't use ridiculous filenames.

Comment: Thanks. Though this method seems to be harder to memorize, I did learn quite a bit about awk from it. Note that it doesn't stop at the first 50 lines, even on an up-to-date Ubuntu install.

Comment: That's odd, I tested it at the time and it never processed anything beyond the first fifty lines of the files I gave it...

Answer (score 3):

In loop way GNU `sed` can do task too :

```
for f in *.sql
do
    sed -e '1 F' -e '51 Q' -e '/pattern/! d' "$f"
done
```

Comment: This doesn't print the file name. Have fun searching the match! ;)

Comment: @don_crissti, yes, `sed -ns '1,50{/pattern/p}'` would work though (but read the files fully so less efficient than awk+nextfile).

Comment: @don_crissti I wonder, which flag is it?

Comment: @FloHimself, he may be referring to the (also GNU-specific) `F` command.

Comment: Note that that code also fails because if the 50th line doesn't match the pattern, 50q is never reached.

Comment: Ah, thank you both! This all feels clumsy. I would go for `find`, `head` and `grep`.

Comment: @don_crissti That is for i change `!d` to `-n .. p`. But to be sure in exit without printing just change `q` to `Q`.

Comment: Now, that fails to match on the 50th line. You can change to 51Q, or do it as `sed -n '1F;/pattern/p;50q'`

Answer (score 2):

Head piped to grep gets you halfway there.

```
head -50 filename | grep string
```

Comment: This won't print the filenames either. Maybe `head -50 file* | grep  'pattern\|==> .* <=='` assuming no other line in those files matches `==> .* <==`